# How to ignore decorator typing

Tags: python, python-decorators, mypy, typing

I use a decorator for a bunch of functions whose argument names and amount differs. I used typing for each function but it gets overridden by decorators typing. Is there a way to ignore it and get type hints for whatever function I want to call?

Example code:

```
from typing import Callable, Any

def decorator(fn: Callable) -> Callable:
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    
    return wrapper


@decorator
def foo_with_decorator(x: int, y: int) -> float:
    return x + y / 2

def foo(x: int, y: int) -> float:
    return x + y / 2

foo_with_decorator(10, 5) # (...) -> Any

foo(10, 5) # (x: int, y: int) -> float
```

I want for both functions `foo_with_decorator` and `foo` to have the same typing. How can it be done?